# Why is my T-SQL cursor executing twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

SQL-Server Code:

```
Declare @offers VARCHAR(100)
Declare @offers_seq VARCHAR(100)

Declare Result Cursor
    For Select Top 1 Offers,Offers_seq From [REZJQWB01]..ActiveBooking_OffersDetails_Seq
Open Result
While @@fetch_status=0
Begin
    Fetch Next From Result Into @offers, @offers_seq
    Declare @value VARCHAR(100) = @offers
    While len(@value) >= 1
    Begin
        Set @value = substring(@value,charindex(';',@value)+1,len(@value))
        Print @value
    End
End
Close Result
Deallocate Result
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to split a set of delimited values present in one cell and then creating a cursor for the complete column. The first time I run this code it gives the below output:

```
2;6;7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
6;7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
12;13;14;17;19;21;
13;14;17;19;21;
14;17;19;21;
17;19;21;
19;21;
21;

2;6;7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
6;7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
12;13;14;17;19;21;
13;14;17;19;21;
14;17;19;21;
17;19;21;
19;21;
21;
```

Ideally It should Print only once but I'm not sure why the loop runs twice. The second time I run this, it gives the output as : 'Command(s) completed successfully'.

Kindly help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is running twice is that you aren't doing the fetch until *after* you've already checked the `@@fetch_status`.

The steps look like this:

1. Check `@@fetch_status`, which is zero, since nothing has been fetched.
2. Fetch a result
3. Run your substring code
4. Check `@@fetch_status` again, which is still zero, because a record was fetched in the previous step
5. Fetch another result, which fails but the cursor is still pointing at the same row as before
6. Run your substring code again, same result
7. Check `@@fetch_status` again, which now returns -1 because the previous fetch failed.

For the same reason as you get two results from running it once, you get nothing the second time, because `@@fetch_status` is -1 from the previous execution.  To fix both issues, you need to fetch before checking the status.  Usually you'll see one of the following methods employed (psuedocode left as an exercise for you to implement).  Typically I use the first option, but some find the second is easier to read:

```
-- (declare and open cursor)
while 1=1 begin
    fetch next from cursor
    if @@fetch_status <> 0 break;
    -- (do stuff)
end
```

or

```
-- (declare and open cursor)
fetch next from cursor
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
    -- (do stuff)
    fetch next from cursor
end
```

Comment: As an aside, I should also mention that I try and avoid cursors if at all possible.  There's a lot of overhead involved, so if you can get away with a plain loop, or even better a single query, always do that in preference to a cursor.  Do a Google search for "avoid t-sql cursor" for some good alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @pcdev for the answer. Helped solve my problem. I understood that I was trying to use the @@fetchstatus incorrectly. Also I'll try if possible to avoid the cursor. Pasting the correct code below.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code:

```
Declare @offers VARCHAR(100)
Declare @offers_seq VARCHAR(100)

Declare Result Cursor
    For Select Top 1 Offers,Offers_seq From [REZJQWB01]..ActiveBooking_OffersDetails_Seq
Open Result
While 1=1
Begin
    Fetch Next From Result Into @offers, @offers_seq
    If @@fetch_status <> 0 Break;
    Declare @value VARCHAR(100) = @offers
    While len(@value) > 1
    Begin
        Set @value = substring(@value,charindex(';',@value,2)+1,len(@value))
        Set @value = ';'+@value
        If len(@value) <= 1 Break;
        Print @value
    End
End
Close Result
Deallocate Result
```

Result:

```
;6;7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
;7;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
;8;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
;9;12;13;14;17;19;21;
;12;13;14;17;19;21;
;13;14;17;19;21;
;14;17;19;21;
;17;19;21;
;19;21;
;21;
```